# Ubuntu does not recognize my geforce 540M

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my graphics card to be recognized in System Info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)

When I go into system info, it says "graphics unknown". Can Ubuntu 11.10 be made to recognize my 540M Geforce driver?

Does it matter?

Unity seems to be working fine (I installed bumblebee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also checking the same problem out some days ago. I even installed the 175.xx, 280.xx and 285.xx drivers. Same thing. So the problem is not related to a version but maybe some data that the Nvidia drivers are not sending to the windows/gui/system. Tested a 6200, 8400, 9500 and gt400.

For the part about if it matters or not, basically nothing changes, except if you would like to see there the name of the video card. The system will work great as it would with or without that particular window showing the name of the video card.

The video card will run just fine, will perform excellent and you will not have any problem if it does not show there. the only bad thing I have seen is that the name is not shown there, but heck, I did not buy a video card just to make it appear in a window did I ^^. I want performance and seeing that you have that particular video card you are REALLY into performance.

Comment: As of the recent updates to 11.10, system info now recognizes my Intel integrated graphics card

Comment: I was actually looking for this post but did not find it. Since an update a week ago the name is shown in the System Info Overview section and Graphics section correctly. Not talking about the 540M but also the GT220, GT440 and GT460 which I have tested so far. Just mentioning the latest here.